# Using click_link with Cucumber Scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I have the following Feature file which is attempting to visit a page, select a link then edit user data.

```
Scenario: Edit an existing member of the club
    Given I go to the member list page
    And I choose the first item
    And I fill in the "First Name" with "Bloggs
    When I press "Update"
    Then I should be on the member list page
    And I should see "Bloggs"
```

and the member_step.rb file contains

```
Given /^I choose the first item$/ do
    #save_and_open_page
    visit members_path
    click_link "1"
end
```

My routes.rb file has

```
Gfs::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :members
end
```

The problem is that I can't get the **click_link "1"** step to work.  The intention is that it will

1. Navigate to the '/members' index page
2. The index page displays a list of users each prefixed with a number, that is the link.
3. Select the link

What I know is that the index page does display a list, my route works ('/members), but my Cucumber is failing and I'm not ***basking in the glory of green***.

The **save_and_open_page** diagnostic shows only the title of the index page and not the details, as though the controller is not accessing the data

Suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a Background where you create the members data? If not, it may be that the data does not exist.

I'd also suggest adding a step like

```
And I should not see "Bloggs"
```

before you update the record.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your cuke correctly, you really won't see the "1" link because:

```
Given I go to the member list page <-- first step
And I choose the first item <-- second step
```

...which expands to:

```
Given I go to the member list page <-- first step
visit members_path
click_link "1"

why are you visiting the member's path after you just visited the member list page? you should be checking that you ARE in the member's path. Something like:


Given I have existing users(generate members here using factory or whatever)
And I go to the member list page( go to member page)
When I follow "1" (click the first member)
Then I should be on the "1"'s member page
When I fill in...etc you get the point
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Makes sense and is clearer, but still no joy since I'm not seeing the link for the first member.  Could it be that I'm not generating the members?  I had assumed that by visiting the members index page there would simply be the list of the existing members.

Comment: like i said above, you need to generate them using factory or machinist or whatever you use for fixtures

Comment: thanks - that was the issue - I had forgotten to setup the data correctly, assuming that it was already in the DB.  Beginners 'Doh' moment

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest that IFF the "1" is a true html anchor link, then you might consider using

```
And I follow "1"
```

You could easily wrap this in your own syntax to make it more aesthetically pleasing but the `And I follow...` step is one that you get out of the box in web_steps.rb.

Another gain in using that one is that you can use a selector to make the click more specific:

```
And I follow "1" within ".my-kickbutt-div"
```

Or something along those lines.

Another thing to check into. If you have @javascript enabled you might be seeing incorrect data in your save_and_open_page. My app is javascript/ajax heavy and I have to open the output in a browser with javascript turned off to see what is really visible there :P This might not be your issue, but just in case...

Comment: good suggestion but it seems the OP's problem isn't that he can't click it, rather cuke doesn't see the link it's supposed to click..because it's not in the page

Comment: understood. the intent of my suggestion (I should have been clearer) was to remove the unknown quantity of his custom step so he was at a more "out of the box" point. I should have said that up front...